# How to find year-wise reputation achieved?

Tags: support, reputation

I want to check how much reputation I have achieved on a yearly basis. I searched in the portal but was unable to find out how to do it. Can you please help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You look it up on the annual leagues - you need at least 200 reputation to show up IIRC

[image]

Find your username for the site (That's you there), go to the site using the dropdown, pick a year, paste your name in and it will show you the reputation for the year and your annual rank.